# Discrete Math Onto and One-to-one functions

Tags: functions

Which of the following functions is one-to-one?  Which is onto?  Explain why.

1. $f:  \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ given by $f(m) = m + 2$
2. $g:  \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ given by $g(m) = 2m^2 – 7$

Comment: Thank you for the verification.  I was just following the instructions given by the website when posting.  I understand the difference between onto and one-to-one functions, but I don't understand how to find or apply.  The N and Z are confusing, because it has been 20 years since I took algebra.

Answer (score 2):

Apply the definition of a one-one function that is: $$f(x)=f(y)\longrightarrow x=y$$ So for the first one you have $$x+2=y+2, ~~x,y\in\mathbb N$$ Indeed, $x=y$. Is this function onto? If it is onto, for every natural number ,say $y$, we should search another natural number $x$ such that $f(x)=y$. Or $$x+2=y$$ Now think of $y=1$, for example.

Comment: How about when $y = 1?$ ;-) +1

Comment: I forgot to click a TU after commenting! Feel free to edit your answer with the question: "Is there an $x \in \mathbb N$ such that $x + 2 = y$ for $y = 1$? If not, then the function is not ONTO."

Comment: We've all been there! No harm done!

Comment: I'm sorry.  Can you dumb this down for me a bit more? Are you putting the x+2 in for the m+2?

Comment: I've been doing well in the class so far, but this problem I just have no clue.  It is an online class, so I have limited interaction with the professor.

Comment: I don't understand where the x+2 and y+2 is coming from.

Comment: @Nell: What is $f(x)$? or $f(y)$? If we consider $x+2=f(x)=f(y)=y+2$ in which $x,y$ are naturals, then the cancellation rule allows us to have $x=y$.

Comment: so the x and the y represent any natural number, which is being substituted for the m in the expression?

Comment: @Nell: Exactly!. In fact you have a rule called $f$ which is ready to get a natural number as an input. Here, we have to work on the outputs first while checking being one-one.

Answer (score 1):

We show (i) $g$ is not one-to-one and (ii) $g$ is not onto.

(i) The key fact here is that the square of, for example, $-2$ is the same as the square of $2$. Thus $g(-2)=8-7=1$ and $g(2)=8-7=1$. We have found an $x$ and a $y$, with $x\ne y$, such that $g(x)=g(y)$.

(ii) We give two ways of seeing that $g$ is not onto. Let $y=-10$. We show there is no integer $x$ such that $g(x)=y$.

If $g(x)=-10$, then $2x^2-7=-10$, and therefore $2x^2=-3$. This is impossible, since $2x^2$ is always $\ge 0$.

Or else we show that there is no integer $x$ such that $g(x)=4$.  For if $g(x)=4$, then $2x^2-7=4$, and therefore $2x^2=11$. This is impossible, since $2x^2$ is always even, while $11$ is odd.